# grunt-contrib-uglfy minified file not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

i'm new to **angularjs** as well as **grunt**. I'm using "**grunt-contrib-uglify**": "^1.0.1" to uglify javascript files and place them into one file i'm getting corect output file as expected. but when i use it in html file getting module inject error.

I tried for uglifying individual file seperately used them in html file worked perfectly as expected without any error.

I also tried for grunt-contrib-concat and use its output to uglify  but result is same (module inject error).

It means when i place multiple javascript files in to one file, angular is not creating injector for my application.

can anybody explain what is happening here?

Comment: You need to specify dependancy for each controller,service,provider explicitly. The angular injector can not identify the dependancy if you give the function inline. Can you post some minimal, verifiable code.

Comment: I have used array notation (bracket) for defining the contollers factory and application config block i don't think that is the ploblem i mean all the dependencies are specified inside array notation.